# Different Pages Based On Form Fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that I would like to redirect to different pages based on what I select based on the state form field.

```
<form action="capture.php" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="_FirstName" required/>
  <input type="text" name="_LastName" required/>
  <input type="tel" id="phone" name="_Phone" required/>
  <input type="email" name="Email" required/>

  <select name="_State" id="state" required>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
  </select>

  <input id="submit" type="submit">

</form>
```

This is the JavaScript code I am using based off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777024/submit-button-action-depending-if-field-matches-another-form) post. Problem is I keep going straight to the 'capture.php' page no matter what state options I select.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit   {
    if(document.getElementById('state').value == 'AZ' ||
   document.getElementById('state').value == 'AR' || 
   document.getElementById('state').value == 'CA') ||
   document.getElementById('state').value == 'CO') ||
   document.getElementById('state').value == 'CT')
{
window.location.href == "warranty.php";
}
else
{
window.location.href == "capture.php";
}
</script>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: Should the JavaScript code be in the header of the html page?

Comment: The form action is capture.php. so if you use input submit, it will go to capture.php

Comment: function submit   { ... syntax error.

Comment: where do you want to handle state value and to make the redirect? into the page which contains the form itself or in capture.php page?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `window.location.href` instead try and set the action property of the form.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").action = "form_action.asp";
```

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_form_action.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax error in your `submit()` function:

- You are missing the `()` for your function.
- Having some extra brackets `'CO')` or `'CA')`.
- Use single = sign for window.location

**Modified Function:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit()   {
  if(document.getElementById('state').value == 'AZ' 
    || document.getElementById('state').value == 'AR' 
    || document.getElementById('state').value == 'CA' 
    || document.getElementById('state').value == 'CO' 
    || document.getElementById('state').value == 'CT')
  {
    window.location.href = "warranty.php";
  }
  else
  {
    window.location.href = "capture.php";
  }
}
</script>
```

**Side Note:**

You can also use `window.open` like:

```
window.open('capture.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several bugs in your code e.g :

1. The two equals sign `==` used for comparaison and not for value assignment.
2. `select` tag is not a self-closed tag so you sould remove `/` at the end :

   ```
   <select name="_State" id="state" required/>
   _________________________________________^
   ```
3. Some extra parenthese `(` in your condition.
4. Missing parenthese in function declaration.

Then i can't see where are you calling `submit()`.

---

IMO add on `submit` event will be better, after click on submit button change the action of then submit form programmatically :

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){

    if(document.getElementById('state').value == 'AZ' ||
       document.getElementById('state').value == 'AR' || 
       document.getElementById('state').value == 'CA' ||
       document.getElementById('state').value == 'CO' ||
       document.getElementById('state').value == 'CT')
    {
        $('form').prop('action', "warranty.php");
    }
    else
    {
     $('form').prop('action', "capture.php");
    }

    return true;
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that there is nothing linking your form submission to your javascript function. So when you validate the form, it goes directly to the adress provided in the "action" attribute.

**Simple solution**

change the markup of your button to this, so the click will be linked to the function call :

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="submit()">
```

**With Jquery :**

load jquery with your page, and add an id to your form like this :

```
<form id="myform" action="capture.php" method="post">
```

add this code in your document :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // this prevent the form from going to capture.php
        submit();
        return false;
    });
});
```